# Can't Update Google AdMob in iOS Project

Tags: ios, swift, admob, cocoapods

I've integrated Google AdMob into my iOS(Swift) project using Cocoapods. It's working fine.

When I first saw the log message regarding there is an update for AdMod, I ran `pod update` BUT the message still gets logged and tells me to update AdMob.

From the output of `pod update`, I see that AdMob is at it's latest version. v 7.8.1 but somehow Xcode does not recognise the change.

Any ideas?

**Update**

My Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'En Yakın' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Ara Bul
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'

end
```

Comment: Seem Xcode has problem, so you can reset Xcode then open again.

Comment: @CuongNguyen I've reseted and even deleted Derived Data many times with no luck 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version at the time of your question should be 7.9.1.

Did you try update(verbose)?. I recommend you download the cocoaPods applications, makes managing your pods much easier.

https://cocoapods.org/app

Once installed and you open a pod file, you will have 3 options at the top right (install, install verbose and update verbose). I would try them and see if it pushes to the latest update.

If that doesn't work, maybe try uninstalling the SDK from cocoa pods. Restart your xCode project and try installing the pod again.

If that also doesn't work that I would try installing the AdMob SDK directly via

pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'.

I am not sure what the difference is between the regular one and the firebase one, maybe the firebase one slightly different.

Note: As member Eric Lichtenschlag has so kindly pointed out

AdMob sometimes does releases outside of the Firebase release cycle, and updates the Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK pod. However, when Firebase releases, their Firebase/AdMob pod depends on a specific version of Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK so that it's stable and your Firebase experience doesn't change in between Firebase releases. Currently, the latest Firebase release is pointing to Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK 7.8.1. On the next Firebase update, it will point to the latest version of AdMob, which is currently 7.9.1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Funny, I was just about to try the Cocoapods application. :] Let's see...

Comment: Defiantly, makes it much easier to use. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: If the latest version is 7.9.1, I'm still on 7.8.1 because that what Cocoapods retrieves even after `verbose(update)` through the app.

Comment: Strange. Are you are calling it like this in the pod file " pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' ". ? Maybe uninstall (comment out) the SDK and than try installing again. Latest version should defiantly be 7.9.1

Comment: Maybe its because you are doing it through firebase. I usually install the pod directly via pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' . I am not sure what the difference is, maybe the AdMob firebase SDK is slightly different.

Comment: Wow, it worked, Thanks, man. :] It's a really weird situation with Google Ads. Could please edit your answer to reflect the changes so I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: Thats great, I also just updated my answer. Thanks for marking. Happy coding.

Comment: AdMob sometimes does releases outside of the Firebase release cycle, and updates the Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK pod. However, when Firebase releases, their Firebase/AdMob pod depends on a specific version of Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK so that it's stable and your Firebase experience doesn't change in between Firebase releases. Currently, the [latest](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/Firebase/3.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json#L35) Firebase release is pointing to Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK 7.8.1. On the next Firebase update, it will point to the latest version of AdMob, which is currently 7.9.1.

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment. If you don't mind, since my answer is already marked, I will add this comment to it.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue and can u please say explicitly how to "install the pod directly via pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' ." Can u please explain how to install DIRECTLY. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, sorry for late reply. By installing directly I mean either get the admob SDK (not firebase SDK which includs adMob) from google and copy it into your project or preferably install cocoa pods / Carthage (check tutorials online) and install the SDK via those dependency managers